# ASP.NET MVC 3: Editor templates for fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html-table

```
<tr>
   <td>
        @Html.Label("Notes") </td><td> @Html.TextArea("Notes")
   </td></tr>
   <tr><td>
        @Html.Label("Action Date")</td><td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Due, new { @class = "dateTimePicker" })</td><td>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Due)
   </td></tr>
```

Anyway I can create a template that will take any `@HTML.Label`, `@Html.Textbox` etc etc, and their `for` counterparts and place them into a table properly? without me having to polute all my views with table markups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most certainly can. I have pieced together a quick sample based upon your sample code:

Given a basic model:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Action Date")]
    public DateTime Due { get; set; }
}
```

And this simple controller:

```
var model = new Foo { Notes = "Some Note String", Due = System.DateTime.Now };
return View(model);
```

You could call an editor template from your view:

```
 @Html.Editor("Editor", "Foo", Model)
```

Given this template:

```
@model StackExamples.Models.Foo

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Notes)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(x=>x.Notes)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Due)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Due, new { @class = "dateTimePicker" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Due)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And have your output rendered as desired without the additional table markup in your views.

Comment: What if its not based on a model entirely? but a mixture of model fields and new fields. So, basically you have to call DropDownList, TextBox, TextArea, DropDownListFor together, and place them into one table.

Comment: @Doomsknight that also would work. If for example you are rendering a viewmodel, the editor template could be based upon that model. The html helpers are their to make it easier to render your views as desired. The combination to use depends entirely on what you want to have rendered.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here:

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html

Comment: Thanks, Ive already looked there, and from what I understand, this only applies to `Html.DisplayForModel()` and `Html.EditorForModel()`. (I use these templates)

Comment: Also for `Html.DisplayFor` and `Html.EditorFor`